# Grep a string recursively in all .htaccess files

Tags: linux, .htaccess, grep

How can I grep for a certain string recursively in all .htaccess files?

```
grep -r -n -H -I 'string' .htaccess
```

doesn't seem to work.

I'm on a GNU Linux system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cd to a folder before the folders that store the htaccess

```
$find . -name ".htaccess" -exec grep -r -n -H -I 'string' {} \;
```

Comment: find is a powerful way to walk a directory tree, the exec flag is a nice way to run commands against the results of the find command.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--include` option:

```
grep -rnHI 'pattern' --include=.htaccess .
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify to 'find' that it needs to look for regular files only:

```
  $ find /usr/local -type f -name ".htaccess" -exec grep -rnHI 'pattern' {} \;
```

You can specify from where your search should begin. For this example, 'find' will look into all directories and sub directories under /usr/local.